# Pushing in Gitkraken, does it use force with lease?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I use force push with lease quite often when rebasing in my work, I wanted to know if gitkraken, under the hood, when clicking on force push, does it run a force push, or force push with lease.

Answer (score 2):

It runs a bare and simple force push.

I am a big fan of rebasing, squashing and amending my own commits, all operations that require to force push. To clarify any doubt, I did a test to see if the force push was running with the lease option and it does not.

If you want to check it yourself:

1. Clone your repository on two different folders: *folder_A* and *folder_B*
2. Create a branch from one of the two repos, push it to origin, and make sure both repositories check it out.
3. Go to *folder_B*, modify any file, commit and push.
4. Go to *folder_A*, **do not fetch** modify any file, amend your latest commit and push.

You will see that the repository in *folder_A* will have overwritten any changes made from *folder_B*.

If you try to pull from *folder_B* you will see it is on a broken state as the commit it was referencing to has been destroyed.

EDIT: shortly after having tested this myself I sent an email to GitKraken, asking if the feature of pushing with lease was going to be enabled anytime soon. They said that they have multiple requests for it. Surely it will be interesting to check the situation in some time to see how it is proceeding.

Comment: “I am a big fan of rebasing, squashing and amending my own commits, all operations that require to force push” They do? I’m a big fan of those things too, and I’ve never force pushed in my life. Are you sure you’re doing this right?

Comment: @matt, are the most pristine GIT user ever existed? :p. Amending: Commit something, push to your own remote branch, see a typo, amend the commit. Now, when you want to push the amended commit, it will find that the same commit already exists and you'll need to force push. Rebasing: checkout master, start a branch, work a day on it and push at the end of the day. The following day someone pushes something on master, you rebase your whole branch and, when you want to push.. you also need to force push :) With squashing it is the same mechanism.

Comment: Okay so all of this seems to be because you're pushing prematurely? Just to take the second scenario: of course if I discover master has progressed I rebase my working branch on top of it, but no "force" is needed because I never pushed it in the first place. I push it when all my ducks are in a row and it's time to merge (pull request).

Comment: @matt I guess it is just a stylistic choice. If I call it a day and I have a worked on a bunch of stuff, I push it. The following day I might have to do the same and if I had to rebase in the meantime there will be a force-push. I guess I could keep everything on local, but I also do not see the need of it (nor the advantages). I force push and I am not ashamed of it ;)

Comment: And your co-workers have permitted you to live this far, so I guess it's okay! :))))

Comment: I guess it is @matt :D I assure you no one is bothered. We're talking about my work branches after all, no one depends on them. I'd even say that not being worried about playing dirty allows me to keep them super tidy and impeccable. You should try one of these days, maybe you'll even like it! :p

Comment: Any idea on the situation now?