# What command precisely does Gitkraken use to push?

Tags: git, github, aws-codebuild, gitkraken

Can anyone explain how to reproduce this behaviour seen with Gitkraken push:

With a github repo setup with an Amazone CodeBuild web-hook, Gitkraken push will *always* trigger a build, even if the remote (Github) branch is on precisely the same commit as my local branch.  I can do this repeatedly to re-trigger a build and it's pretty useful effect.

Yet when I open a command prompt in the exact same repo locally and type:

```
git push
```

Nothing happens, amazon CodeBuild doesn't re-build.

---

When I [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246735/453851) the suggestion is that Gitkraken uses a "regular bare git push", yet I can't explain the difference in behaviour.

Comment: FWIW : their FAQ section on this point : [How can I see what commands GitKraken makes to the cli ?](https://support.gitkraken.com/faq/#how-can-i-see-what-commands-gitkraken-makes-to-the-cli) is not very helpful, but indicates they are using an embedded git library, so perhaps GitKraken's behavior will not exactly match one of the cli commands

Answer (score 0):

GitKraken commands do not directly correlate to actual git commands because it uses [libgit2](https://libgit2.org/) for all of it's git operations. Looking at the Activity Logs gives you an idea what it is doing but no actual commands.

[image: GitKraken Activity Log]